# Change Display Name of a PXSelector field

Tags: acumatica

I need to add a search field for employees to the Order Entry page, SO301000.  As was suggested at the Framework and Customization training I recently attended, I searched for what I wanted on another page and came up with the following code from the Requests page where there is a selector for employees called Requested By.

```
[PXViewName(EP.Messages.Employee)]
public PXSetup<EPEmployee, Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, 
Equal<Optional<RQRequest.employeeID>>>> employee;
```

This adds a selector which displays a full list of employees to the Sales Order page just as I want but the Display Name for the field is Employee ID and I need to change it to Contract Reviewed By. Try as I might, and I have tried, I have not been able to change the display name.  How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please update the post with attributes decorating custom field?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the PXUIField attribute for your page.  The best way to do this is to add a Cache_Attached entry in the BLC extension.

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contract Reviewed by")]
protected virtual void EPEmployee_bAccountID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
        }